# Binary Search Tree - Postorder logic

Tags: logic, binary-tree, binary-search

I am looking at implementing code to work out binary search tree.
Before I do this I was wanting to verify my input data in postorder and preorder.

I am having trouble working out what the following numbers would be in postorder and preorder
I have the following numbers   4, 3, 14 ,8 ,1, 15, 9, 5, 13, 10, 2, 7, 6, 12, 11, that I
am intending to put into an empty binary tree in that order.

The order I arrived at for the numbers in POSTORDER is

2, 1, 6, 3, 7, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8, 13, 15, 14, 4. Have I got this right?

I was wondering if anyone here would be able to kindly verify if the postorder sequence I came up with is indeed the correct sequence for my input i.e doing left subtree, right subtree and
then root.

The order I got for pre order (Visit root, do left subtree, do right subtree) is
4, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 14 , 8, 7, 9, 10, 12, 11, 15, 13. I can't be certain I got this right.
Very grateful for any verification.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the structure of your tree (is it balanced?) nor the order in which you are inputting the data originally. If you do that we can verify your results